# Module uninstall clean-up

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Is there a hook that I can implement in my module so that I can run some clean up code when my module is uninstalled. I create a number of variables using `variable_set()` and I would like to delete these variables when the module is uninstalled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is.

Where you would write an install hook like this :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */   
function annotate_install(){
    // Use schema API to create database table
    drupal_install_schema('annotate');
}
```

The uninstall would look like this :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */   
function annotate_uninstall(){
    // Use scheme API to delete database table
    drupal_uninstall_schema('annotate');
    // Delete our module's variable from variables table
    variable_del('annotate_node_types');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I wasn't looking in the right place for this hook.